# Creating a wcf web service and returning the xml response in android

Tags: c#, android, xml, web-services, wcf

I am an android developer. I want to create an android application which fetches the xml response from a WCF web service using soap. I have created a WCF web service, in which it fetches the XML document and return the content of that document. Here I dont know how to consume that content in android. Moreover, I am new to WCF and I am confused whether I am doing it right or wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

IService.cs

```
namespace WcfXML
{

[ServiceContract (Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    XmlElement GetData();
}
}
```

Service1.svc

```
namespace WcfXML
{

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public XmlElement GetData()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\defaultGraphProperties.xml");
        return xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    }
}
}
```

After creating this, when I run(F5), I am not able to invoke the method. How can I consume this web services in android? Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add configuration for  `webHttpBinding` in `web.config` under the `<Bindings>`.

Then add the below code in `web.config` under the `<System.serviceModel>`

```
      <services>
          <service name="Test_WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfiguration" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="Test_WcfService.IService1"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" contract="Test_WcfService.IService1"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
          </webHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

After doing this changes in `web.config` you will be able to consume the wcf service from Browser.

Replace the `Test_WcfService.Service1` and `Test_WcfService.IService1` with your WCF Service name and interface.

To consume the WCF Service , you will have to do a Soap Request from Android.

Also if possible share your demo wcf service i will make the necessary configuaration changes at my end.

Comment: Thanks for the help!..I ran VS2012 as an administrator. i consumed and did debugging and i was able to retrieve and return the xml file. But the local web service is in local host. How to connect with the local host?

Comment: ok which network is android device connected.If your Android device is connected to the network on which webservice runs you can use your pc IP address and consume the wcf service.